# Fatal error in php while parsing a website

Tags: php, html-parsing

I use simplehtmldom for parsing a website to get all images.

Everytime i add a link the error occurs:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Code:

```
<form method="post">
Link <input type="text" name="link" size="50"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>


<?php


if($link != "")
{
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
        $html = $_POST[link]

    // Find all images 
    foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
    {
        echo $element->src . '<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

TestSite:

http://www.orschlurch.net/2011/11/17/pixxdump-144/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
<form method="post">
Link <input type="text" name="link" size="50"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>


<?php


if($link != "")
{
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
        $html = file_get_html($_POST['link']);

    // Find all images 
    foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
    {
        echo $element->src . '<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

You must use constructor for its member functions `$html = file_get_html($_POST['link']);`

`$html = $_POST['link']` String

`$html = file_get_html($_POST['link']);` Class

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($html));
```

and then call `$doc->find()`